# UWP Using x:Bind to monitor global variables

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, xbind

I have an App that groups all the global variables in a single class. They are used over MANY classes in the App. (300+ variables, shortened for demo):

```
public class Vars
{
    public static string DateStr = "";
}
```

I want to use x:Bind to One-way bind the data to fields on a page:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Local_Data" Text="{x:Bind local:Vars.DateStr, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle1}"/>
```

OneTime binding seems to work OK. I can refresh the page and the DateStr reflects the new value.

I changed the Vars class definition to:

```
public class Vars : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static string _DateStr = "hello";

    public static string DateStr
    {
        get { return _DateStr; }
        set
        {
            _DateStr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

When I try to build, I get the message:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Vars.OnPropertyChanged(string)'

If I change it to:

```
    protected static void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

I get the message:

> Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

I assume that it is something trivial that I am missing. What is the proper way to flag the data changing?

Thanks for your help.
Dan

Comment: in a static method, there is no `this`. Either use null or something else, doesn't matter because the `x:Bind` generated code doesn't check the sender property of the event.

Comment: I don't see how to implement this. Everything I try gives compile errors.

Comment: Can you show me how to modify the OnPropertyChanged routine above?

Comment: with the static method option, change `handler(this, e);` to `handler(null, e);`

Comment: The difficult line is the one preceding it -- PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;

Answer (score 0):

As the error message mentioned, the reason for your issue is that you are using `Static` modifier for the binding source property- `Vars.DateStr`. You just need to remove the `Static` modifier of the `Vars.DateStr` property.

```
  public  string DateStr
    {
        get { return _DateStr; }
        set
        {
            _DateStr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DateStr");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then the DateStr variable is not accessible to the other classes.

Comment: Yep, because of the OnPropertyChanged event needs to be used for a non-static property. You might need to remove the Static keyword for both DateStr property and the OnPropertyChanged method.

Comment: If the DateStr is not static, then the background processes can't access it. Is there any way to OneWay bind global/static variables (that are accessible to the entire program) to fields on a XAML page?

Comment: So you have a background task in your app. May I know it's an in-process or out-of-process background task? You want to access the property so that you could update the UI, right?

Comment: I have timers running in the background, UDP message traffic, and serial port traffic. There are several different screens the access the data.

Comment: What about saving the property into the local setting? Update the local setting every time the property is change.